# Initialise an array with values based on type values

Tags: typescript

I want to initialise an array with values based on a type:

```
type Pets = 'dog' | 'cat';

const PETS: Array<Pets> = []; // ['dog', 'cat'];
```

`Pets` is an ever-changing type, which I need to be represented in `PETS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit trickier with types.
There's the option [A_A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6548154/a-a) proposed which is somewhat common.

If it doesn't necessarily have to be a `type`, you can replace it with an `enum` which will allow you to iterate over it's values.

**Example:**

```
enum Pets {
   Cat = 'cat',
   Dog = 'dog',
}

const pets: Pets[] = (Object.keys(Pets) as Array<keyof typeof Pets>).map(x => Pets[x])

// pets = ['cat', 'dog']
```

To access values in an `enum` you can either use their string value or the lefthand property.

**For example**, both of these should work:

```
const pets: Pets[]

// First option:
if (pets[0] === 'cat') {
   ...
}

// Second option:
if (pets[0] === Pets.Cat) {
   ...
}
```

### Notes:

- Unlike `const enum` (which is not iterable), `enum` types add some JS code to the bundle (which TS normally shouldn't do), keep this in mind going forward.
  For instance, if you have a great number of regular enums in your project it might add quite a bit of code to your bundle, whether or not that's ok depends on you.

Comment: From what I can tell, I can just use an `enum`. Thanks for you post.

Comment: Sure thing! edited the post and added some more info. Note the drawback of enums I've mentioned under `Notes`.

Answer (score 2):

You could initialize the constant and then create the type based on this constant:

```js
const PETS = ['dog', 'cat'] as const
type Pets = typeof PETS[number];
```

It's the other way around, but still you only need to write it once.